# Keeping merged cells in excel and pasting df into certain cells and columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am currently trying to fill empty cells with 1, and keeping the cells with string values (eg. S,R,G,B).

My data source is an excel file which has the following.

Raw Data:

```
Customer ID      1      2    3    4
0010                    R    G    G
                 S      A    A
0599             R                B
0442             A      B
```

***Note that 0010 is a merged cell, while columns 1,2,3,4 is not merged.**

Intended Output Data

```
Customer ID      1     2    3    4
0010             1     R    G    G
 1               S     A    A    1
0599             R     1    1    B
0442             A     B    1    1
```

I would like to keep the merged "Customer ID". 
Is there any way to work around this?
And also can I set the function to apply to only certain rows and columns?
And also to paste the df back to certain rows and columns?

Current Code:

```
data = pd.read_excel('path',header=0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df= df.fillna(1)

df.to_excel('path', index=False)
```

Comment: Could you give a link to a sample Excel file? e.g. using something like Pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying that the `Customer ID` field is an `object`. This should then result in empty values appearing as `Nan`. Then the `fillna()` should work as expected:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('path.xlsx', header=0, dtype={'Customer ID':object})

print(df)
df = df.fillna('1')
print(df)

df.to_excel('path_out.xlsx', index=False)
```

This would display:

```
  Customer ID    1    2    3    4
0        0010  NaN    R    G    G
1         NaN    S    A    A  NaN
2        0599    R  NaN  NaN    B
3        0442    A    B  NaN  NaN

  Customer ID  1  2  3  4
0        0010  1  R  G  G
1           1  S  A  A  1
2        0599  R  1  1  B
3        0442  A  B  1  1
```

If `Customer ID` is a merged cell e.g. merging `A` and `B`, then you could skip over the merged column as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel('path.xlsx', usecols="A,C:F", header=0, dtype={'Customer ID':object})
```

Comment: Is it possible to indicate the exact rows and columns that I'll be reading from?
And also to put the whole df back into another indicated rows and columns? For what I know of is only iterrows which only let me choose the columns and for only 1 column of the DF into a column on excel.

Comment: You can add a parameter `skiprows=5` to skip reading the first 5 rows, and the `usecols` specifies which columns you want. `startrow` and `startcol` can be added to `to_excel()`.